# What is the name of axis-picker like UI element

Tags: scripting, interface, add-on

I'm developing an addon and i would like to use an input that looks like the standard axis picker - can you please provide me some help how can i show something like this on the screen?

[image]

Currently i'm using `EnumProperty` but it looks like a standard combo-box and i would like to be consistent with blender's UI.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [layout.props_enum](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.props_enum) to automatically display the list of Enum properties.

I didn't succeed in displaying them in a row though, so you can iterate over the enum items with  [layout.prop_enum](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.prop_enum) and display them in a row.

Adding `{"ENUM_FLAG"}` to the [bpy.props.EnumProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty)'s `options` parameter lets you select several items with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + Click.

Note that a flag enum returns a `set` containing all the selected items as their string identifier, and not a single string value like regular enum props. If no item is selected, it will return an empty `set()`

[image]

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        row = self.layout.row(align=True)
        row.label(text="Axis")
        row.prop_enum(context.scene, "my_enum", "X")
        row.prop_enum(context.scene, "my_enum", "Y")
        row.prop_enum(context.scene, "my_enum", "Z")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        options={"ENUM_FLAG"}, 
        items=(("X", ) * 3, ("Y",) * 3, ("Z",) * 3)
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Note you can replace the three `layout.prop_enum` lines with  [bpy.types.EnumProperty.enum_items_static](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.EnumProperty.html#bpy.types.EnumProperty.enum_items_static) :

```
for item in context.scene.bl_rna.properties["my_enum"].enum_items_static:
    row.prop_enum(context.scene, "my_enum", item.identifier)
```

Which is a bit more convoluted but cuts on the copy/paste.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer

You can find the code that creates that part of the overlay panel around line 6118 of `space_view3d.py`:

```py
        sub = split.column()
        row = sub.row()
        row.label(text="Axes")

        subrow = row.row(align=True)
        subrow.prop(overlay, "show_axis_x", text="X", toggle=True)
        subrow.prop(overlay, "show_axis_y", text="Y", toggle=True)
        subrow.prop(overlay, "show_axis_z", text="Z", toggle=True)
```

As you can see, the UI consists of a row with a label and 3 buttons, one for each of the three properties `show_axis_...`  So the best thing to do would be to replace the `EnumProperty` with either three `BooleanProperty` values, as the UI does in this case, or a `BooleanArrayProperty` with 3 values, if that's more suitable to your purposes.

### How to locate such things:

If you are going to do Python development, it is good to edit `Preferences` → `Interface` and enable `Developer Extras` and `Python Tooltips`.

Once you've done that, you can often find the source code for part of the UI by hovering over the relevant bit, right clicking, and selecting `Edit Source` from the popup menu.  This will bring the relevant Python into a text block that you can then view in the text editor.

However, that doesn't always work, and in this case it didn't, because *Active Button match cannot be found*.  So I did a bit of research.  Instead of looking for the button, I looked for the panel, by hovering over the icon for the drop down. This brought me quickly to line 786 of the same file:

```py
        sub.popover(panel="VIEW3D_PT_overlay", text="")
```

which told me to look for the source code for the panel `VIEW3D_PT_overlay` class.  But that didn't quiet work because it turns out that the panel is actually composed of a simple header and a series of subpanels.  Fortunately, the relevant subpanel is immediately after the panel in the source code and looking for "Axis" found the code above.